# How do I add a new column to an already existing table with "null: false" and no default?

Tags: elixir, ecto

So I have the following migration:

```
defmodule App.Repo.Migrations.AddTitleToRoles do
  use Ecto.Migration

  def change do
    alter table(:roles) do
      add :title, :string, null: false
    end
  end
end
```

Problem is this migration will fail because of the null constraint:

`12:12:28.961 [info]  alter table roles
** (Postgrex.Error) ERROR (not_null_violation): column "title" contains null values`

In Rails, my solution would have been to first add the field with no constraint, then update the values, then `change_column` to add the constraint.

However, I can't seem to find the equivalent of `change_column` for Ecto.

How can I add a constraint to an existing column?

Comment: Please see my answer to that question; it answers your exact question.

Comment: @Dogbert that worked, thanks.